# How can I write a recursive function based on the outputs of a function python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have to write a recursive function in python that generalizes the following function:

```
f(n)   result
0      1
1      1
2      2
3      5
4      13
5      34
6      89
7      233
```

I made something like this:

```
def F(n):
   if n <= 0:
      return 1
   else:
      return 2*( F(n-1) + F(n-2) ) - F(n-3)
```

It works with almost all values of the range but it doesn't match with the 3 first results so.
How can I determine a recursive function based on the outputs?

I have this information:

**"Hint:** **F(n)** is recursively defined in terms of **F(n-1)** and **F(n-2)**.  You have to figure out the math expression that will make this happen.
**Hint:**   no coefficient of the function in this expression is greater than 5, nor less than 1, and any such coefficient is an integer.**"**

Comment: Is the hint saying that `F(n)` is defined as *exactly* `a*F(n-1) + b*F(n-2)`, where the exercise is to determine what `a` and `b` are?

Comment: The goal is to get the function that produces the result. It doesn't matter how many coefficients you use as they are in the range(1, 5) and the function is based on f(n-1) and f(n-2). In my code f(n-3) should not be there but it was a coincidence

Comment: Ok, but there might be a infinite range of forms to search. For instance, why have you chosen: `2*F(n-1) + 2*F(n-2) - F(n-3)`?

Comment: I used **2*F(n-1) + 2*F(n-2) - F(n-3)** just by coincidence. because using my calculator it matched with the results for the bigger values. but I couldn't get the right answer so I am looking is someone can give an idea of how to solve this type of problem

Comment: I think its a case of just searching for the values of the coefficients. The hint mentions: `F(n-1)` and `F(n-2)`. Are these the only terms you are expected to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need 3 base case

```py
def F(n):
    if n <= 1:
      return 1
    elif(n == 2): #-------->
        return 2
    else:
      return 2*( F(n-1) + F(n-2) ) - F(n-3)
```

or

```py
def F(n):
    if n<= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 3*F(n-1) - F(n-2)
```

Comment: I did not see the problem statement, I was jut pointing that u need 3 base case, lemme check

Comment: Thanks is a good solution. Any advice on how to find the best base case?

Comment: check you n should be >=0 like 0,1,2 so if you don't put the base case `elif(n == 2): ` it becomes `return 2*( F(1) + F(0) ) - F(-1)`, `-1` so you need to put this in the base case

Answer (score 0):

A good source for integer sequences is OEIS. Your sequence has the number [A001519](https://oeis.org/A001519). From there we learn that:

> a(n) = 3*a(n-1) - a(n-2) for n >= 2, with a(0) = a(1) = 1.

Which is the solution @Epsi95 found.

Another nice property of this sequence is:

> This is a bisection of the Fibonacci sequence A000045. a(n) =
> F(2*n-1), with F(n) = A000045(n) and F(-1) = 1